# Problem fetching and mapping data using Contentful in a Vue (or Nuxt) function

Tags: javascript, vue.js, nuxt.js, vuejs3, nuxt3

I'm attempting to fetch and map data from Contentful in my Vue (or Nuxt, if you are using Nuxt.js) application. The purpose is to retrieve entries of the type caseStudies and then map some specific fields for my application to use.

Here's my function to fetch and map data:

```
const fetchData = async () => {
    const response = await client.getEntries({
        content_type: 'caseStudies',
        order: '-sys.createdAt',
        limit,
        skip
    });

    console.log(response);

    return response.items.map((item) => {
        const { id, createdAt } = item.sys;
        const { slug, title, description } = item.fields;
        const featuredImage = item.fields.featuredImage.fields.file.url;
        return {
            id, slug, title, description, featuredImage, createdAt
        };
    });
};

const { data: caseStudies, pending, error, refresh } = await useAsyncData('caseStudies', fetchData);
```

All necessary imports, including client and other related configurations, have been set up correctly in my application.

the function still doesnt work as there is no content saved to `caseStudies`

Comment: can you provide more information? Is there an error in the console?

Comment: @Alex ther is no message in the console